# Using FME to draw polygons around roads using aerial photography

Tags: mapinfo, aerial-photography, fme-form

I am trying to use FME to draw polygons around the extents of road using aerial imagery.

I have a Road Centreline table that I have buffered 5m and put this through a RasterGCPClipper so only the road and a meter or so off the road is shown on the aerial photography (depending on road width). I have the output going through the RasterResampler and then to the RastertoPolygonCoercer.

After this transformer I am stuck since I know the output will be thousands of little polygons the size of the designated cell size I have specified in the RasterResampler.

What I want to do is group on a certain RGB range or something similar. I know this may be a little crude but I just want to see if I can do something like this, and some of the roads have tree coverage that will muck it up too.

I want to output this to MapInfo and I am using an ECW file for the imagery.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not sure that you need the RasterGCPClipper.  A normal Clipper should do. You should be able to use a RasterExpressionEvaluator to pull through the RGB Values that you want.  However, I imagine roads would have greatly varying RGB Values.  Without an infrared band you're prone to errors. But it's worth a shot.  Also a screenshot of your workspace would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Fetzer says, it's going to be prone to error because the RGB values will vary. However - for what it's worth - [here is an FME workspace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6x08520b78rz09a/swimmingPoolDetector.fmw?dl=0) that you can probably adapt to your requirements.

I made this workspace to detect swimming pools in aerial imagery. Basically it extracts the RGB values and compares them to each other. I was looking for cells where blue > red and green > red (also blue and green values should be > 50).

The technique works - it's just that you'll have a harder time picking out roads I think. Pools were easier because so few things in an image are blue.

Anyway, hope this helps!